# Can I show Rich-Text inside Popups which rendered when clicking on 2 buttons inside SharePoint SPFX web part

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I want to build an SPFX web part which render 2 buttons and when the user clicks on the buttons, 2 Popups should be shown + have 2 fields to enter the 2 Popups text, something as follow:-

[image]

So i did the following:-

inside the `MyModalPopupWebPart.ts`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are"
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value"
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description"
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

inside the `MyModalPopup.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

inside the `MYModal.tsx` :-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p>{myprops.WhoWeAre} </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

inside the `MYModal2.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal2 = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p>{myprops.OurValue} </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

Currently the "Who We Are" & "Our Value" fields only allow to enter plain-text, and even if i add HTML code inside the "Who We Are" & "Our Value" fields>> the popup will show the HTML as-is and not as a Rich-Text.
So is there a way to allow my popup to show rich text instead of just a plain-text? either by entering pure HTML code inside the "Who We Are" & "Our Value" fields and allow the popup to render HTML rich text? or have the "Who We Are" & "Our Value" fields as Rich Text editors and allow the popup to render the entered rich text? is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To render the html string in react, we can use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute which is a react version of dom innerHTML property.

```
  <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}>
   </p>
```

Comment: but will this poses any security risk ?

Comment: I am asking because the attribute name indicates this